# Relationship between System.Web.Helpers.Chart and System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts

I want to make a Chart in my MVC 4 web page and tried to use the built in Microsoft Chart. Unfortunately, the Chart in Helper is quite limited and most examples I found revolve around the one in System.Web.UI - but where ist the difference?
Also, I found numerous hints that the one in Web.UI was intended for classic asp.net and is unsuitable for MVC. Can anyone shed some light on that problem?